# Adding characters using Grep style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, grep

2 problems about paragraph style...
can grep style do this?
Thanks!

```
1. if  number is 10 duplicate  four time /  result: 10 101010
2. if number is 8 add 3 character like this "*" / result: 8 ***
```

Comment: No... Grep styles can only find a string and apply a character style to that string. It can't make any text changes. The find and change dialog can make changes with grep, but it's not dynamic the same way grep styles are, it's just a static text replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Grep Styles (found under the Paragraph Style Options window) only work for **formatting** specific queries, **NOT** replacing text.

You should use a custom Find/Replace for this, and if you need to run this multiple times, you can save specific search queries.

Comment: ok..find and replace options

find number "10" and add *** / 
rezult 10 ***
when replace can I skip "10" and change color only for *** with same action?

Comment: Run the replace, then to change the color on anything updated _after_ the replace, use GREP styles.

Comment: Here's how to add text using the Find-and-Replace: https://creativepro.com/indesign-grep-essentials-how-to-add-delete-and-re-arrange-text/